# Can I generate a new .git folder again for my project?

Tags: git, version-control, bitbucket

I am not so into GIT and I have the following problem.

I have a Java project that was under GIT and was associated to a remote BitBucket repository. The problem is that for an error I have removed the **.git** folder (and I can't retrieve it).

Can I generate a new .git folder associated to this repository in some way?

Comment: Have you deleted the .git folder in your local / testing environment or from master branch ?

Comment: @BinaryBrackets 'master branch' does not refer to the 'remote' (github/gitlab/bitbucket etc.) - you can have the 'master' branch locally.

Answer (score 3):

Two ways:

You could simply [clone the repo again using](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone):

```
git clone http://your/repo/url
```

or you could reinitialize the git folder and [create the connection between your local folder and the repo manually](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes):

```
git init // initializes the .git dir
git remote add origin http://your/repo/url // adds your bitbucket repo as origin url
git remote -v // verify it worked and the connection is stable
git pull origin master // pull and see if your up-to-date
... // do whatever you like from here, add, commit, push
```

Comment: Ok, I think that the second solution is better because in my project I have some unpushed changes. So if I do git itnit and then I add the remote and then I pull...I will lost these changes?

Comment: @AndreaNobili No that won't happen. The only thing that could happen is that you get a conflict and have to merge your changes. You can just add and commit your changes like before.

Answer (score 1):

Since the local repo is connected with bitbucket, you'd better **clone this repo to another directory and then copy your current changed file into it**. Finally commit and push changes to bitbucket.

If you created a new `.git` folder, all the commit history will be lost. If the history is unnecessary for you, of cause you can create `.git` folder in an empty path and then move files into this path.

Answer (score 0):

Just make a new clone of your Github project. A new `.git` folder will be created.